# Shopify graphQL query

Tags: django, graphql, shopify-app

I can't see how to format this graphene query for shopify.  I need to replicate this curl query with graphene in Django:

```
    curl -X POST \
"https://<shop>.myshopify.com/api/graphql" \
-H "Content-Type: application/graphql" \
-H "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token: <storefront-access-token>" \
-d '
{
  shop {
    collections(first: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          handle
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

So far I have:

```
access_token = 'some_token'
    headers = (
        { "Content-Type": "application/graphql" },
        { "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": access_token},
    )
    schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
    print(schema)
    result = schema.execute('{
        catsinuniform {
            collections(first: 5) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  handle
                }
              }
              pageInfo {
                hasNextPage
              }
            }
        }'')
    print(result.data['catsinuniform'])
```

This syntax is wrong for graphene but I don't get how it should look? Once I have the data in the right format I can then do a requests post to get the informaiton I want from the shopify storefrontapi

Comment: Are you trying to create a graphql request, or use graphene to replicate the data structure on shopify?

Comment: I need to create a graphql request so I can access the shopify storefront api. This page https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/getting-started#accessing-the-storefront-api-graphql-endpoint has all the info I need if I could use python to make the requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphene is an implemention of the GraphQL spec for Python, meant for creating and executing your own GraphQL schema. It is **not** a GraphQL client for making requests to existing GraphQL servers. You can make calls to the Shopify API using any regular HTTP library, like `requests`, or you can use something like [gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql). A simple example:

```
import requests

access_token = <YOUR TOKEN>
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/graphql",
    "X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token": access_token
}

query = """
{
  shop {
    collections(first: 5) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          handle
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

request = requests.post('https://<YOUR SHOP>.myshopify.com/api/graphql', json={'query': query}, headers=headers)
result = request.json()
```

Comment: This looks good but I'm still getting errors: {'errors': [{'message': 'Parse error on "query" (STRING) at [1, 2]', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column': 2}]}]}

Comment: Try changing the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`

Comment: Just getting rid of the content type seems to work best - then I go through sub dictionaries of the json using ['data']['shop']['collections'] - but this does work - all it took was getting rid of the content type

Answer (score 1):

As of version 5.1.0 of the Shopify Python API, support for querying the Shopify Admin API with Graphql is included:

```
client = shopify.GraphQL()
query = '''
    {
        shop {
            name
            id
        }
    }
'''
result = client.execute(query)
```

[Shopify Python API Graphql Docs](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api#graphql)